# will human do whatever they like if money is not human's objective?

Tags: scientific-realism

suppose we are living in 3000AD where money is not human's objective. Then the question is:
will human do whatever they like if money is not human's objective?

Comment: This seems more like a psychology question than a philosophical one, but either way it is hard to imagine that in 1000 years there will be _no_ limits on resource use per person, so I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean BC or AD? Either way, this question will attract many opinion based answers in its current form and is as such not a good question for this platform.

Comment: i think the question is misleading because lots of people pursue things other than money (sex, status, whatever), whether or not they have more than a trivial concern for others

Comment: @Mathematician I rolled back your edit because it changes the essence of the question. This kind of edits are good, but should be done in dialogue with the OP.

Comment: Scientific Realism is not the right tag for this. Perhaps use "ethics"

Comment: @RexKerr:  Yes, it is hard (essentially impossible) to imagine that in 1000 years there will be no resource constraints, but on the other hand, it's almost equally hard to imagine that in 1000 years we'll still be using money.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that humans always have, and always will, do whatver they like, subject to the constraints they face.

Comment: Just in passing: there are communities on SE (i.e., [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com)) that *do* contemplate counter-factuals

Answer (score 1):

Humans will go towards whatever motivates them (may not necessarily be money).Abraham maslow
has done a greate deal of research on what motivates humans ,and why different people may be motivated by differnt things. :http://www.simplypsychology.org/maslow.html